# Robotframework checkbox is not clickable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, automated-tests, robotframework

i really try difference staff to try that this script works but no way, i used name, id, selector, xpath didnt work, i use click element, checkbox should be selected, select checkbox, click button, really i do not understand what i am doing wrong.

this is the website code for the check box [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5anZn.png)

this is my robotframework script:
click element  css=#nutzungsbedingungen

and this is the error that appears on my terminal:

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable at point (354, 445). Other ele
ment would receive the click: ...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

That is because the driver is not focusing in the page - for some reason it gets off the page. When it happens to me, I usually click to focus on the nearest element that I want to check.

The other reason could be that there is an iframe, so first you should be get into the iframe and then could check the box.